# Rails! How to have styles appear last instead added to application.css

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im a newbie to Ruby and Rails and wanted to know how to add custom.css to be last css file call in DOM.

Also, if I need Js to be last and not above the header, what's the correct way of doing this.

Currently everything coming from the assets folder in Rails order.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "custom", :media => "all" %>
```

to the bottom of the layouts file and add `custom.css` to your precompile list:

```
# /config/environments/production.rb

config.assets.precompile += %w( custom.css )
```

But your `application.css` file will still compile with `custom.css`.

You can stop it compiling in application.css by setting which files are included in the `application.css` file. Change,

```
# /app/assets/stylesheets/application.css

/*
 *= require_tree .
 */
```

to

```
/*
 *= require first_css
 *= require second_css
 */
```

which will ignore the `custom.css` file. It's very similar for the javascript. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html for more info.

Comment: So, I'm going this will work the same for JS file but only add the link to the bottom of the application layout.

Comment: Yes but with `javascript_include_tag` and different syntax in the application.js file, `//= require first_js` instead of `*= require first_css`. Also add custom.js to the precompile list.

Answer (score 0):

In your layout.erb you can include everything you need under your layout itself

Comment: How to remove it from the top so it don't duplicate top and bottom.

Comment: In your appliction.css/js change `*= require_tree .`, to `require_directory .`, and then include all rest files in subfolder. However you have to add in `config/environments/your_env` files for precompile, otherwise you'll be getting errors

Comment: Would I remove it from assets pipeline and create new directory for special css and js that's higher priority.

Comment: I still would like to include the other css and javascript in the assets pipeline. Just need 1 css to be last in the header and 1 js file to be added to the bottom of the body.